# e-mail ratelimit exim

Tags: linux, email, email-server, exim, rate-limiting

Server1 sending to Server2:

```
Connecting to domain.com [1.1.1.1]:25 ... connected
  SMTP<< 451 Temporary local problem - please try later
  SMTP>> QUIT
LOG: MAIN
  SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection: host domain.com [1.1.1.1]: 451 Temporary local problem - please try later
LOG: MAIN
  == alerts@domain.com R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp defer (0): SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection: host domain.com [1.1.1.1]: 451 Temporary local problem - please try later
LOG: queue_run MAIN
  End queue run: pid=42746 -qff
```

Server2:

```
2013-02-13 19:35:07 1U5mn3-0006KF-Ft Completed
2013-02-13 19:38:36 SMTP connection from [1.1.1.1]:10702 (TCP/IP connection count = 1)
2013-02-13 19:38:36 no IP address found for host 1.1.1.1.choopa.net (during SMTP connection from [1.1.1.1]:10702)
2013-02-13 19:38:36 H=(host.domain.com) [1.1.1.1]:10702 F=<> rejected RCPT <alerts@domain.com>: "
2013-02-13 19:38:37 H=(host.domain.com) [1.1.1.1]:10702 F=<> rejected RCPT <alerts@domain.com>: "
2013-02-13 19:38:37 H=(host.domain.com) [1.1.1.1]:10702 F=<> rejected RCPT <alerts@domain.com>: "
2013-02-13 19:38:37 H=(host.domain.com) [1.1.1.1]:10702 F=<> rejected RCPT <alerts@domain.com>: "
2013-02-13 19:38:37 H=(host.domain.com) [1.1.1.1]:10702 Warning: "Detected session with all messages failed"
2013-02-13 19:38:37 H=(host.domain.com) [1.1.1.1]:10702 Warning: "Increment slow_fail_block Ratelimit - (host.domain.com) [1.1.1.1]:10702 because of all messages failed"
2013-02-13 19:38:37 SMTP connection from (host.domain.com) [1.1.1.1]:10702 closed by QUIT
2013-02-13 19:38:37 SMTP connection from [1.1.1.1]:10723 (TCP/IP connection count = 1)
2013-02-13 19:38:38 no IP address found for host 1.1.1.1.choopa.net (during SMTP connection from [1.1.1.1]:10723)
2013-02-13 19:38:38 H=[1.1.1.1]:10723 temporarily rejected connection in "connect" ACL: "Host is ratelimited due to multiple failure only connections (5.8/1h max:5)"
2013-02-13 19:38:38 SMTP connection from [1.1.1.1]:10725 (TCP/IP connection count = 1)
2013-02-13 19:38:38 no IP address found for host 1.1.1.1.choopa.net (during SMTP connection from [1.1.1.1]:10725)
2013-02-13 19:38:38 H=[1.1.1.1]:10725 temporarily rejected connection in "connect" ACL: "Host is ratelimited due to multiple failure only connections (5.8/1h max:5)"
2013-02-13 19:38:39 SMTP connection from [1.1.1.1]:10735 (TCP/IP connection count = 1)
2013-02-13 19:38:39 no IP address found for host 1.1.1.1.choopa.net (during SMTP connection from [1.1.1.1]:10735)
2013-02-13 19:38:39 H=[1.1.1.1]:10735 temporarily rejected connection in "connect" ACL: "Host is ratelimited due to multiple failure only connections (5.8/1h max:5)"
2013-02-13 19:38:40 SMTP connection from [1.1.1.1]:10740 (TCP/IP connection count = 1)
2013-02-13 19:38:40 no IP address found for host 1.1.1.1.choopa.net (during SMTP connection from [1.1.1.1]:10740)
2013-02-13 19:38:40 H=[1.1.1.1]:10740 temporarily rejected connection in "connect" ACL: "Host is ratelimited due to multiple failure only connections (5.8/1h max:5)"
2013-02-13 19:38:40 SMTP connection from [1.1.1.1]:10741 (TCP/IP connection count = 1)
```

How do I remove the ratelimit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your ratelimit database.  That's just a fancy name for the local db4 cache file that exim maintains with ratelimit state information (since it's a db file and not in memory, the state can survive exim restarts and server reboots).

On an rpm based system, it would probably be located at `/var/spool/exim/db/ratelimit*`.  I suggest that you first stop exim, and I mean completely stop it.  On rpm based systems that means `service exim stop; service exim stop` (that's right, twice).  Then delete the file including ratelimit.lockfile if it's present.  Then start exim back up, it will create the ratelimit cache file again when it needs it.